# Neato LDS intensity data

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, xv-11, neato, node

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The Neato LDS scanner returns the angle, range, intensity, and an error code. The neato_driver.py from the XV-11 node does not look at the intensity.  I want to use the intensity data to help detect 'bright' obstacles marked by reflective tape.
How can the driver by modified to return intensity data.  My Python skills are non-existant.  my first attempt failed. Can I do a pull request still on the Git repository. (Fergy and Ralph probably have better things to do with their time.

???? Code ?????
def getScanRanges(self):

```
    """ Read values of a scan -- call requestScan first! """
    ranges = list()
    intense = list()
    angle = 0

    if not self.readTo("AngleInDegrees"):
        self.flush()
        return []

    last=False
    while not last: #angle < 360:
        try:
            vals,last = self.getResponse()
        except Exception as ex:
            rospy.logerr("Exception Reading Neato lidar: " + str(ex))
            last=True
            vals=[]

        vals = vals.split(",")

        if ((not last) and ord(vals[0][0])>=48 and ord(vals[0][0])<=57 ):
            #print angle, vals, intense
            try:
                a = int(vals[0])
                r = int(vals[1])
 #                   i = int(vals[2])
                e = int(vals[3])

                while (angle < a):
                    ranges.append(0)
  #                        intense.append(0)
                    angle +=1

                if(e==0):
                    ranges.append(r/1000.0)
  #                       intense.append(i/1000.0)
                else:
                    ranges.append(0)
 #                       intense.append(0) 
            except:
                ranges.append(0)
 #                    intense.append(0)
            angle += 1
   if len(ranges) <> 360:
    rospy.loginfo( "Missing laser scans: got %d points" %len(ranges))

 #        return ranges, intense
     return ranges
```

---

The following code with comments(#)  removed does not abort, but rostopic echo /scan shows  intensities[ ]

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/296160/neato-lds-intensity-data/) by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 147 on 2018-07-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

(assuming reading the intensity the way you do is correct...)
If this is the only file you touched, this obviously does not work. You only return the intensities, but you also have to write it into the `sensor_msgs/LaserScan` message that is published.

Add it in the respective driver node [here](https://github.com/mikeferguson/neato_robot/blob/hydro-devel/neato_node/nodes/neato.py#L89).
The line should then read:

```
scan.ranges, scan.intensities = self.robot.getScanRanges()
```

You can obviously send a PR, they will probably have some feedback or change requests. But just go ahead (if there are contribution guidelines in the repo, make sure to follow them)

P.S. Next time, please add a link to the repo you are modifying. I first only found one ROS driver written in C++.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-07-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DrBot](https://answers.ros.org/users/765/drbot/) on 2018-07-04**:
Thank you, your answer was correct!  by adding scan.intensities to the neato_node/neato.py file, I am able to get both ranges and intensities.

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-07-05**:
Great that it works @DrBot. If the answer is correct, please klick the checkmark next to the question to mark this as solved.